# LaTeX set up automatic line break not to stretch previous line

Tags: formatting, line-breaking, hyphenation

I am sure this is some basic LaTeX document formatting, but for the sake of me I just can't find the right place in the documentation on the proper way to achieve what I want.

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\sloppypar

\begin{document}
    Some normal line followed by a cyrillic long word многодългадуманакирилицабезпренасяне
\end{document}
```

I know `\sloppypar` is a bad practice, but it really did manage most of my warnings and document flaws in an acceptable way, so I'm sticking to that for now.

This example compiles with an `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 9--10` warning, which is understandable since LaTeX doesn't have instructions on how to hyphenate the cyrillic word in question and thus puts it on a whole new line, while trying to stretch the previous line, which ends up as `Underfull`. I get this. (And by the way, this is not Russian, but Bulgarian, and I didn't find any hyphenation packages for that... so advices on that note are also welcome).

**Essence:** I really don't have the time to reformat my whole document right now, so I'd want to instruct LaTeX simply not to try to stretch the previous line (basically break it like with `\\` where needed), which satisfies me completely for now. So the document should look as if its content was the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\sloppypar

\begin{document}
    Some normal line followed by a cyrillic long word\\ многодългадуманакирилицабезпренасяне
\end{document}
```

For now, I'm actually fixing the couple of spots (maybe 10 or 15 lines) where this problem occurs, by manually adding the `\\` and I know it's horrible and hardly managable in the long term, so I'd be really glad on some instructions on how to enforce such behaviour (in combination with `\sloppypar` if that's possible).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you mentioned, you couldn't find any hyphenation packages for the bulgarian language, https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-bulgarian might be interesting.

Comment: If your document is mostly in english with some bulgarian words in it, the following should sork: `\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\sloppypar

\begin{document}
    Some normal line followed by a cyrillic long word \foreignlanguage{bulgarian}{многодългадуманакирилицабезпренасяне}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you, will definitely take a look when I have the time! For the sake of learning and understanding tho, I'd still like some insight on the main topic!
P.S. The document is mainly in Bulgarian.

Comment: Do you actually mix english and bulgarian text in your document or was this mix just for the sake of a minimal example? Depending on how the contents of your document look like exactly, a different solution might be preferrable.

Comment: @leandriis No, I don't mix languages in text mode. The english text was only for the sake of inline explanation of the situation... I only occasionally use small bits of english notations in math mode, which AFAIK is another matter of formatting?

Comment: If you use bulgarian text only, a simple `\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}` should already result in the expected output.

Comment: As mentioned, it is a really neat practical feature I'll consider and most likely solves the problem with hyphenation. But that was rather a side note. The main question remains, provided I'd like to actually get the whole word automatically transferred to a new line, but just without stretching the previous one. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Should the rest of your text stay fully justified and just this one line of text (the line before the too long word)  should be left aligned or do you prefer your whole text left aligned?

Comment: Whole text left aligned. Best would be also an ability for paragraph-wise redefinition of this formatting (which I think is possible anyways), but the default of my whole document is left-aligned.

Comment: But if your text is left-aligned anyways, the whole "stretching"  problem should not occur. This issue is a side-effect of justified text as opposed to left aligned text. Please clarify what kind of alignment you have in your document and which one you want to have.

Comment: I see, okay. Well, in the MWE the same behaviour is observed, so I guess that's the default? I've not actually specified any additional paragraph alignment, the original behaviour seemed just fine to me... up until this point. So maybe that's what I've got to do?

Comment: I'm still not sure if that's what you're after, but if you want left aligned text rather than the default justified text, you can add `\raggedright` after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: As an alternative to using `babel` with an appropriate language option, I'd just add discretionary hyphens in appropriate places and let (La)TeX choose the one(s) that give the best breaks.  A discretionary hyphen consists of a backslash followed by a hyphen `\- ` and it works very reliably.  (It's sometimes needed in all-English texts for words that should be hyphenated, but automatic hyphenation can't be applied because it's different depending on whether the word functions as a verb or a noun, like "progress".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that no one has suggested using "discretionary hyphens".  A discretionary hyphen is input as backslash-hyphen (`\-`) in locations in a word where hyphenation is appropriate.

Discretionary hyphens are sometimes needed in English text where a word that can and should be hyphenated cannot be hyphenated automatically, because (La)TeX can't tell whether it's a verb or a noun, and the break should be in a different place depending on whether the word is used a a verb or a noun, for example "`pro\-gress`" (verb) vs. "`prog\-ress`" (noun).

Let's try this with your long cyrillic word:

`много\-дълга\-дума\-на\-кирилица\-без\-пре\-насяне`

(La)TeX will choose the break(s) that will give the best spacing within the current paragraph.

(Please don't assume this is entirely correct.  My grasp of Bulgarian is rather shaky; I could probably do better with Russian.)

**Addendum:**

The OP has noted in a comment that the document in question contains more than just a smattering of Bulgarian text.  In that case, this approach is almost certainly preferable:

```
\usepackage[bulgarian]{babel}
```

@leandris has proposed the following in a comment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
 \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[english]{babel}
% \sloppypar
\begin{document}
Some normal line followed by a cyrillic long word
\foreignlanguage{bulgarian}{многодългадуманакирилицабезпренасяне}
\end{document}
```

I recommend checking the `babel` documentation to determine how to deal with more extensive packages of the "other" language.

Comment: Your grasp of Bulgarian is astoundingly correct, with exception for the last two syllables of the last word! Thank you for the suggestion! But as mentioned in the comments, my document is mainly in Bulgarian where this behaviour occurs. The english text in the example was just for the read to grasp the problem. Do you have any suggestions for the main question? How to force LaTeX to break the lines as with `\\`?

Comment: If the bulk of the document is Bulgarian, then using `babel` with the `[bulgarian]` option is undoubtedly preferable.  But in that case, this question is almost certainly a duplicate.  (I haven't looked for one, but it likely wouldn't specify Bulgarian.)  I'll add that to the answer though; even with good hyphenation patterns for Bulgarian, an occasional discretionary might be useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed information!

Answer (score 5):

TeX has been multilingual for many years.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[bulgarian,english]{babel}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show page margins

\begin{document}

Some normal line followed by a cyrillic long word 
\foreignlanguage{bulgarian}{многодългадуманакирилицабезпренасяне}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If your document is mainly in Bulgarian, with English text, swap:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show page margins

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{english}{Some normal line followed by a cyrillic long word} 
многодългадуманакирилицабезпренасяне

\end{document}
```

If you don't like that hyphenation because of the compound word, you can use `"=` to set a compoind word boundary. Here's the result and also the complete hyphenation in this case.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,bulgarian]{babel}

\usepackage{showframe} % to show page margins

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{english}{Some normal line followed by a cyrillic long word}
многодългадумана"=кирилицабезпренасяне

\parbox[t]{0pt}{\hspace{0pt}многодългадуманакирилицабезпренасяне}

\end{document}
```

[image]

From the documentation of `babel-bulgarian`:

[image]

Note that `‘‘` should really be `"` (undirected double quote), so the real shorthands are

```
"-
""
"~
"=
",
```

Comment: I'm really grateful for the provided examples and the detailed explanation!